# Commit window not showing changed files, BitBucket, Xcode

Tags: xcode, bitbucket

I had an ugly glitch when I was committing one of my Xcode projects to BitBucket. I thought it was just a wifi connection issue but there's something else going on. I've tried to commit several other projects and they are all exhibiting the same problem. I have attached a screen-shot of the window that opens when doing a commit. There are files that have been changed but they do not show in the commit window. I don't see any Xcode settings that were changed. Has anybody experienced this?

[image]